# no such file to load -- RMagick.rb Rails, Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubygems, rvm, rmagick

I have ruby and my gems installed in my home directory using rvm. 'require RMagick' works from the console and irb, but not from within my Rails app. I have the gem listed in my Gemfile.

```
require 'RMagick'

class PetsController < ApplicationController
  def image
    image = Image.new(image_path("base/Base.png"))
    #image = Pet.composite(0, '4a4a4a')
    @response.headers["Content-type"] = image.mime_type
    render :text => image.to_blob
  end

end
```

If I remove the require from my controller, I get

```
uninitialized constant PetsController::Image
```

I also have tried `require 'RMagick'` in boot.rb, and by referring to the Image object using `Magick::Image` (which gives me `uninitialized constant PetsController::Magick`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! Restarting the server fixed it. I guess I hadn't restarted the server when I added rmagick to my gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are running the rails app with another user than the one that has the `RMagick` gem installed?

Comment: I'm using the WEBrick server for development, it's running as me.

Comment: Try adding `require 'rubygems'` at the top of your files and see if that doesn't solve the problem